# If $x_n \in M$ for all $n$ where $M$ is closed subspace of $H$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly then $x \in M$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

If $x_n \in M$ for all $n$ where $M$ is closed subspace of $H$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly then $x \in M$.

By the definition of a closed subspace we have that $x_n \in M$ converges to some $x \in H$ such that $x \in M$. Why do we need the weak convergence condition here? Isnt the statement obvious from the definition of the closed subspace?

Comment: It is not true that weak converges implies convergence in norm (this holds only in finite dimensional spaces). What you have to show is that $M$ is weakly closed. This is an easy   exercise based on Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: what is definition of a closed subspace which is infinite dimensional? Or is my definition ok, but im interpreting it incorrectly? So it does not mean that $\|x_n-x\|_H < \varepsilon$, but  just that $x_n$ converges to some $x \in H$ such that $x \in M$?

Comment: I think you should go over the definitions again. A closed subspace means that if $x_n\to x$ in norm and $x_n\in M$ for all $n$ then it follows that $x\in M$. But here you don't know that $x_n\to x$ in norm, but rather that $x_n\to x$ weakly. The meaning of weak convergence is that for all bounded functionals $f\in H^*$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Comment: ah i see! so $M$ is WEAKLY closed subspace, then this makes sense to me. So i did interpret the notation in correctly.

Comment: @voroshilov No, $M$ is a closed subspace in the usual sense. (closed in norm, I wrote the definition in the comment above) However, $x_n\to x$ is only WEAKLY convergent. We don't know that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in norm, and so the fact that $M$ is closed doesn't immediately imply that $x\in M$.

Comment: thanks i see that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x \not\in M$ then we have that $dist(x,M) > 0$. By the Hanh-Banach theorem there exists a bounded linear operator $f$ such that $f(M) = \{0\}$, $\|f\| = 1$ and $<x,f> = dist(x,M)$, but this is a contradiction since $<x,f> = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}<x_n,f> = 0$, hence $x \in M$.

Comment: Alternatively you can use Mazur's theorem, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970273/if-a-sequence-converges-weakly-in-a-closed-subspace-m-of-a-banach-space-then).